# how to stop insert data into database on refresh the page using codeigniter

Tags: html, codeigniter

It is my insert function.It inserts data well and shows data in the other view. but it has a problem.if I refresh the view page it inserts again.I want to prevent inserting again on refresh page.
plzzzzzzzzzzzzz

view

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="insert_controller">
<input type="text" placeholder="plate number" name="plate">
<input type="text" placeholder="maker" name="maker">
<input type="text" placeholder="model" name="model">
<input type="text" placeholder="year" name="year">
<input type="text" placeholder="color" name="color">
<input type="text" placeholder="drive" name="drive">
<input type="text" placeholder="phone" name="phone">
<input type="text" placeholder="name" name="name">
<input type="text" placeholder="city" name="city">
<input type="text" placeholder="country" name="country">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
<a >cancel</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

It is my controller.After insert data, its result is good and into searching_view page. but when I refresh the searching_view page it inserts data again .i wants to avoid insert data again on refresh the searching_view page.

controller

```
class car extends CI_Controller {
  public function insert_controller() {
      $data['search']=$this->m->insert_model();
      $this->load->view('searching_view',$data);
  }
}
```

it is model .it inserts data and get data from database and send the result .

model

```
class add_model extends CI_Model {
  public function insert_model()
   {
    if ($this->input->post('submit')) 
    {

    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Karachi');
    $date=date('g:i A').' on '.date('F d,Y');
    // echo "<pre>";
    // die(print_r($date, TRUE));
    $plate = $this->input->post('plate');
    $phone = $this->input->post('phone');
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('car');
    $this->db->where('plate', $plate);
    $this->db->or_where('phone', $phone);
    $d = $this->db->get();
    if ($this->db->affected_rows()>0)
     {
         redirect('http://localhost/Ci/index.php/Car/error_message2');
      }
      else
     {
      $arr= array(
                 'plate'  =>   $this->input->post('plate'),
                 'maker'  =>   $this->input->post('maker'),
                 'model'  =>   $this->input->post('model'),
                 'year'   =>   $this->input->post('year'),
                 'color'  =>   $this->input->post('color'),
                 'drive'  =>   $this->input->post('drive'),
                 'phone'  =>   $this->input->post('phone'),
                 'name'   =>   $this->input->post('name'),
                 'city'   =>   $this->input->post('city'),
                 'country'=>   $this->input->post('country'),
                 'date'  =>   $date
                  );
                  $this->db->insert('car', $arr);

                  $id= $this->db->insert_id();

                  // fetching

                  $this->db->select('id,plate,maker,model,year,color,drive,phone,name,city,country');
                  $this->db->from('car');
                  $this->db->where('id', $id);
                  $d = $this->db->get();
                  return $d->result();
       }
     }


  }
}
```

Comment: your insert and listing method should be different. I mean after insert complete your should use `redirect` instead of loading `searching_view`

Answer (score 2):

Well usually your browser should warn you before you send another POST-request. But if you want to completely avoid that possibility, you can do the following things:

1. **make a redirect**
2. (use [CSRF-tokens](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf))

The second solution will return an error when trying to resend data, so it shouldn't be used without a redirect as users will simply get an error on reload.